# Chrome: Reader mode no longer available

Tags: google-chrome

I noticed reader mode is no longer an option in `chrome://flags/`. I am running chrome `Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. Is there a way to manually enable reader mode?